# Java Swing based game framework. Any advice?

Tags: java, swing, frameworks, java-2d

I'm developing game using Java Swing framework. Does anyone know good framework based on Swing? Mostly I care about performance of redrawing.

Comment: have a look at Play Framework and read FAQ of this site

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov The Play framework is a framework for webapps, not for Swing apps, and does not have anything to do with games, despite the name "Play".

Comment: @Jesper, you are right, sorry. Swing is a kind of framework itself

Comment: It depends, how complex are we talking?  2D or 3D?

Comment: @mkorbel, we're trying to [nuke game-development](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154731/135887), please don't add it back.

Answer (score 4):

Swing is fine for simple games, but if you really care about performance of redrawing, you should probably take a look at one of the frameworks based on OpenGL. Examples:

- http://www.lwjgl.org/ - quite a low level library but very fast. basically raw OpenGL.
- http://www.slick2d.org/ - a popular and fairly easy to use 2D game library.
- http://jmonkeyengine.com/ - a good choice if you want a full 3D engine.

In particular, if you want to do more complex effects (lots of colours, shading, transparency effects for example) then you will probably need OpenGL.

Comment: +1 yes these are some nice frameworks

Comment: slick2d has been moved to http://slick.ninjacave.com

Answer (score 3):

This simple Fixed Time Step game loop (I adapted from reference credit to the author) has never let me down.

It will allow drawing at exactly 60 fps (or whatever you make it) the hertz can be changed too, it enables anti-aliasing via Graphics2D and a few other effects as well.

The original authors example included interpolation checking but I found it giving me a few problems in my games like pictures flickering in and out of their positions so I have kept that included but if you experience problems at least you will know what is causing it):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameLoopTest implements ActionListener {

    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton quitButton;
    private JButton pauseButton;
    private boolean running = false;
    private boolean paused = false;

    public GameLoopTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fixed Timestep Game Loop Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        gamePanel = new GamePanel(500, 500);
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
        pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        quitButton.addActionListener(this);
        pauseButton.addActionListener(this);

        buttonPanel.add(startButton);
        buttonPanel.add(pauseButton);
        buttonPanel.add(quitButton);
        frame.add(gamePanel);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GameLoopTest();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object s = e.getSource();
        if (s == startButton) {
            running = !running;
            if (running) {
                startButton.setText("Stop");
                pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
                runGameLoop();
            } else {
                startButton.setText("Start");
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } else if (s == pauseButton) {
            paused = !paused;
            if (paused) {
                pauseButton.setText("Unpause");
            } else {
                pauseButton.setText("Pause");
            }
        } else if (s == quitButton) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    //Starts a new thread and runs the game loop in it.
    public void runGameLoop() {
        Thread loop = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gameLoop();
            }
        });
        loop.start();
    }

    //Only run this in another Thread!
    private void gameLoop() {
        //This value would probably be stored elsewhere.
        final double GAME_HERTZ = 30.0;
        //Calculate how many ns each frame should take for our target game hertz.
        final double TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000000000 / GAME_HERTZ;
        //At the very most we will update the game this many times before a new render.
        //If you're worried about visual hitches more than perfect timing, set this to 1.
        final int MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER = 5;
        //We will need the last update time.
        double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
        //Store the last time we rendered.
        double lastRenderTime = System.nanoTime();

        //If we are able to get as high as this FPS, don't render again.
        final double TARGET_FPS = 60;
        final double TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;

        //Simple way of finding FPS.
        int lastSecondTime = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

        while (running) {
            double now = System.nanoTime();
            int updateCount = 0;

            if (!paused) {
                //Do as many game updates as we need to, potentially playing catchup.
                while (now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES && updateCount < MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER) {
                    updateGame();
                    lastUpdateTime += TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                    updateCount++;
                }

                //If for some reason an update takes forever, we don't want to do an insane number of catchups.
                //If you were doing some sort of game that needed to keep EXACT time, you would get rid of this.
                if (now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) {
                    lastUpdateTime = now - TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                }

                //Render. To do so, we need to calculate interpolation for a smooth render.
                float interpolation = Math.min(1.0f, (float) ((now - lastUpdateTime) / TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES));
                drawGame(interpolation);
                lastRenderTime = now;

                //Update the frames we got.
                int thisSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);
                int frameCount = gamePanel.getFrameCount();
                if (thisSecond > lastSecondTime) {
                    System.out.println("NEW SECOND " + thisSecond + " " + frameCount);
                    gamePanel.setFps(frameCount);
                    frameCount = 0;
                    lastSecondTime = thisSecond;
                }

                //Yield until it has been at least the target time between renders. This saves the CPU from hogging.
                while (now - lastRenderTime < TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS && now - lastUpdateTime < TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) {
                    //allow the threading system to play threads that are waiting to run.
                    Thread.yield();

                    //This stops the app from consuming all your CPU. It makes this slightly less accurate, but is worth it.
                    //You can remove this line and it will still work (better), your CPU just climbs on certain OSes.
                    //FYI on some OS's this can cause pretty bad stuttering. Scroll down and have a look at different peoples' solutions to this.
                    //On my OS it does not unpuase the game if i take this away
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    now = System.nanoTime();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateGame() {
        gamePanel.update();
    }

    private void drawGame(float interpolation) {
        gamePanel.setInterpolation(interpolation);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gamePanel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    float interpolation;
    float ballX, ballY, lastBallX, lastBallY;
    int ballWidth, ballHeight;
    float ballXVel, ballYVel;
    float ballSpeed;
    int lastDrawX, lastDrawY;
    private int frameCount = 0;
    private int fps = 0;
    int width, height;

    public GamePanel(int width, int height) {
        super(true);
        ballX = lastBallX = 100;
        ballY = lastBallY = 100;
        ballWidth = 25;
        ballHeight = 25;
        ballSpeed = 25;
        ballXVel = (float) Math.random() * ballSpeed * 2 - ballSpeed;
        ballYVel = (float) Math.random() * ballSpeed * 2 - ballSpeed;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setInterpolation(float interp) {
        interpolation = interp;
    }

    public void update() {
        lastBallX = ballX;
        lastBallY = ballY;

        ballX += ballXVel;
        ballY += ballYVel;

        if (ballX + ballWidth / 2 >= getWidth()) {
            ballXVel *= -1;
            ballX = getWidth() - ballWidth / 2;
            ballYVel = (float) Math.random() * ballSpeed * 2 - ballSpeed;
        } else if (ballX - ballWidth / 2 <= 0) {
            ballXVel *= -1;
            ballX = ballWidth / 2;
        }

        if (ballY + ballHeight / 2 >= getHeight()) {
            ballYVel *= -1;
            ballY = getHeight() - ballHeight / 2;
            ballXVel = (float) Math.random() * ballSpeed * 2 - ballSpeed;
        } else if (ballY - ballHeight / 2 <= 0) {
            ballYVel *= -1;
            ballY = ballHeight / 2;
        }
    }

    public int getFrameCount() {
        return frameCount;
    }

    public void setFrameCount(int frameCount) {
        this.frameCount = frameCount;
    }

    void setFps(int fps) {
        this.fps = fps;
    }
    private final static RenderingHints textRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    private final static RenderingHints imageRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    private final static RenderingHints colorRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    private final static RenderingHints interpolationRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    private final static RenderingHints renderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    public void applyRenderHints(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setRenderingHints(textRenderHints);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(imageRenderHints);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(colorRenderHints);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(interpolationRenderHints);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(renderHints);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        //applys effects like anti alising for images and tetx, as well as sets the renderinf value to quality etc
        applyRenderHints(g2d);

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        int drawX = (int) ((ballX - lastBallX) + lastBallX - ballWidth / 2);
        int drawY = (int) ((ballY - lastBallY) + lastBallY - ballHeight / 2);
        g2d.fillOval(drawX, drawY, ballWidth, ballHeight);

        lastDrawX = drawX;
        lastDrawY = drawY;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("FPS: " + fps, 5, 10);

        frameCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've started my own [Swing Game Library](https://github.com/davidkroukamp/SwingGameLibrary) which someone might find useful if not to use then simply to borrow some concepts from it.

**Reference:**

- http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,24220.0

Comment: I can't believe how long I just watched that awesome red dot... +1

Comment: @FakeMan see final update it should run like a charm